# Find commit that first added a particular line of code on Github

Tags: git, github

I would like to find the commit that added the following lines of code to [solver.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp) for the deep learning library [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/), which is hosted on Github. I am not a contributor or have any special permissions. How do I do that?

```
template <typename Dtype>
void SGDSolver<Dtype>::ClipGradients() {
  const Dtype clip_gradients = this->param_.clip_gradients();
  if (clip_gradients < 0) { return; }
  const vector<shared_ptr<Blob<Dtype> > >& net_params = this->net_->params();
  Dtype sumsq_diff = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < net_params.size(); ++i) {
    if (this->net_->param_owners()[i] < 0) {
      sumsq_diff += net_params[i]->sumsq_diff();
    }
  }
  const Dtype l2norm_diff = std::sqrt(sumsq_diff);
  if (l2norm_diff > clip_gradients) {
    Dtype scale_factor = clip_gradients / l2norm_diff;
    LOG(INFO) << "Gradient clipping: scaling down gradients (L2 norm "
        << l2norm_diff << " > " << clip_gradients << ") "
        << "by scale factor " << scale_factor;
    for (int i = 0; i < net_params.size(); ++i) {
      if (this->net_->param_owners()[i] < 0) {
        net_params[i]->scale_diff(scale_factor);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you have to clone the repository to your machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
```

Simply use [`git-blame`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) to find out who committed a certain line:

```
git blame -L 123,123 path/to/file.cpp
```

Or, for a range of lines, use `-L 100,150` or similar. You may want the option `-M` which detects if lines were moved.

You can also use [`git-log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for the entire commit log:

```
git log -L 123,123:path/to/file.cpp
```

Answer (score 5):

Responding to the **title** of this question specifically, rather than the description (as googling a search-phrase similar to the question title brought me here), I would recommend the following:

Clone the repository to your machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
```

Then search the git log for all the commits where the search term is present:

```
git log -S searchTerm
```

Finally, tail the output in order to only see the oldest commit, as this must be the commit where that **particular line was first added**:

```
git log -S searchTerm | tail -4
```